# CSS: Align multiple lines of text left after a radio button

Tags: css, text, alignment, lines

[image]

Unfortunately I don't really know how to describe the problem with the correct terms, I used CSS very sparingly so far.

Problem: the second line of the lowermost radio option should be aligned with the first (where I drew the vertical line). of course the radio button itself should stay where it is.

Should be easy but like I said I don't know the terms to describe this properly

Comment: Place radio buttons absolutely or use flexbox.

Comment: put you code in questions

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

There are some approaches to make this structure. You can use [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). On the other hand you can place radios absolutely inside some relative container.

**Flexbox**

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-1">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-2">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum d</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-3">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

**Absolute positioning**

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Absolute</h1>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-1">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-2">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum d</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="val-3">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: your code compresses all radio buttons into one! input position has to be relative ->the above isn't aligned either in ie or firefox. by fiddling around aimlessly I got the buttons and labels to align in ie, but they were off in firefox then. form#ausfluganmform fieldset.food label{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: red;
}

form#ausfluganmform fieldset.food input{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }

form#ausfluganmform fieldset.food span{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
   }

Comment: @LMTR14 Not sure I understand what you are talking about. FF [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ywmatUN.png), IE [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/T4qdUbH.png). All works fine. You didn't paste you code, so I don't know does it work or not. But code snippets above work fine.